# Function that can be used in sql statement

Tags: sql, database, function, oracle10g, sql-function

I have a sql which returns 3 records

```
select emp_no from employees where dept_no='S3407'
```

results

```
1089
2092
1999
```

I need to use the above SQL in a function and function should return all three values.
I would like to use this function in another sql statement like the following

```
select * from emp_history where emp_no in ('1089','2092','1999');
```

In the above sql I would like to use the function instead of hard coded employee numbers.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

As the query is quite complex as what I have mentioned above is only a sample of the query as the full query cannot be pasted here. So I need to use a function to achieve this.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Regards

Comment: Do you know that you can combine the two queries into one?: `select * from emp_history where emp_no in (select emp_no from employees where dept_no='S3407');`

Comment: @ypercube Yes I am aware of that, but I need to have a function to achieve this because this is only a small part of the query as the query us quite complex. Thanks

Comment: I don't see why a function is needed. If you want to use the results in multiple places/stemenents/queries, you could either keep the results is a temporary table or use a CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to consider Andomar suggestion by the following reasons:
1. views permit to provide enough level of encapsulation
2. CBO works nearly perfect with views so your query will work more or less predictably depending of number of records.

Once you replace the views by a function you will face the case when CBO can't estimate the cardinality of function so you have either to submit full scan or implement kind of package in  order to calculate the cardinality of the function.

So +`1 to Andomar

Surely you could use pipelined functions and rewrite the query as

```
 select * from emp_history where emp_no in (select * from table(your pipelined function))
```

but as I explained before it's not the best way

You could find the perfect article (by my opinion) about pipelined functions in the link http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php

Comment: cursors can be used like sys_refcursor? If I am using sys_refcursor will there be a problem of closing cursor in the sql where I am calling the function? Thanks

Comment: If you use pipelined it's not matter what's in the guts of the function: either explicit cursor (weak sys ref or static one) or implicit (like FOR LOOP statement) or BULK collect statement

Comment: I created a pipelined function, how do I call this in my sql because when I try to use the following way I am getting `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got` SQL `select * from emp_history where emp_no in (select my_func('S3407') from dual);`

Comment: If you have a look into my answer more closely you will find the exact example how PF should be used. It is clearly explained in the link I gave you as well.

Comment: Opps I missed that. Thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a view:

```
create view vw_MyView 
as
select  emp_no 
from    employees 
where   dept_no = 'S3407'
```

And you can use that view in a second query:

```
select * from emp_history where emp_no in (select emp_no from vw_MyView);
```

Comment: As the query is quite complex as what I have mentioned above is only a sample of the query as the full query cannot be pasted here. So I need to use a function to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create subquery on this without using a function.

```
SELECT *
FROM   emp_history
WHERE  emp_no IN 
        (
            SELECT emp_no
            FROM employees
            WHERE dept_no = 'S3407'
        );
```

Comment: Reason why I would want a function is later stage this query could because this is only a small part of the query as the query us quite complex. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following approach.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetEmpNos 
(   
    @dept_no varchar(10)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT emp_no from employees Where dept_no = @dept_no
)
GO
```

And use this function like below.

```
select * from emp_history where emp_no in (select * from dbo.GetEmpNos('S3407'));
```

For oracle 10g, try to use the following code.

```
CREATE TYPE my_emp_type_coll IS TABLE OF my_emp_type; 
/ 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_emp_no (p_dept_no IN VARCHAR(10))  
RETURN my_emp_type_coll PIPELINED IS 
BEGIN 
  FOR emp IN (SELECT * FROM employees WHERE dept_no=p_dept_no) LOOP 
  PIPE ROW(my_emp_type(emp.emp_no)); 
  END LOOP; 
  RETURN; 
END; 
/ 

SELECT * FROM emp_history WHERE emp_no IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_emp_no('S3407')));
```

Comment: I am using Oracle 10g. Thanks